# newUri Output differs for Asp,Net Core Docker Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, uri

I have created an ASP core web application and getting the root path of a folder present within wwwroot of the project.

Created Asp core web application by enabling docker with Linux and windows mode. I am using characters like Č, Š, Ž etc in the folder name. For example, assume the name is "ČVOR". Executing this code in Linux docker with the below code, the path is provided as

```
new Uri("/app/wwwroot/ČVOR").Host
```

The result is

```
"/app/wwwroot/%C4%8CVOR"
```

When there are no special characters, the Uri returns an empty string.

For example, below code returns an empty string

```
new Uri("/app/wwwroot/CVOR").Host
```

But in Windows docker, the path will be as "C:\app/wwwroot/ČVOR" and it returns "" empty string.

Can someone please suggest whether any sample configurations have to be changed for this difference between both modes? How the special characters can be processed with new Uri?

Regards,

Keerthana.

Comment: Also take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1#international-resource-identifier-support - idk if its relevant here.

Comment: also `"C:\app/wwwroot/ČVOR"` this is a filepath whilst in previous examples you've used `"/app/wwwroot/CVOR"`

Comment: Also see this quick fidlde: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFpWV8